# Like timeago, but in the future

Tags: jquery

There is this cool jQuery plugin called [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) which converts time from the past into a human readable format.

I would like a similar thing for the future. (I am working on a TV programme scheduler.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](http://timeago.yarp.com/) (home page in fact):

> To support timestamps in the future, use the allowFuture setting:
>
> `jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;`

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6b4kG/1/).