# Seconds into time elapsed in JS

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to convert a total amount of seconds into time elapsed using jQuery and struggling.

I have as an example : `{"expires": "254254"}` response from an external source, I want to convert this into `2days Xhours Xminutes left`, I have tried using something like this :

```
function timeDifference(elapsed) {
    var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
        var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
        var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
        var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
        var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;
    if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
            return Math.round(elapsed/1000) + ' seconds ago';   
        } else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
            return Math.round(elapsed/msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';   
        } else if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {
            return Math.round(elapsed/msPerHour ) + ' hours ago';   
        } else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
            return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerDay) + ' days ago';   
        } else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
            return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerMonth) + ' months ago';   
        } else {
            return 'approximately ' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerYear ) + ' years ago';   
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to also describe what output you get, and why it doesn't match with what you expect.  For one thing, it will never say exactly what you ask because the string "left" is not even in the function.  Please be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**--Update**

```
     function DDHHMMSS(seconds){
            var t = seconds
            var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
                cs =    60 * 1000,
                d = Math.floor(t / cd),
                h = Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
                m = Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000),
                s  =   Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch ) / 360000),
                pad = function(n){ return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; };
            if( m === 60 ){
                h++;
                m = 0;
            }
            if( h === 24 ){
                d++;
                h = 0;
            }

            var days =  d.toString() + "days";
var hour =  pad(h).toString() + "Hours";
var minutes = pad(m).toString() + "Minutes";
var Seconds =  pad(s).toString() + "Seconds";

            return [days , hour , minutes ,Seconds].join(':');
        }
```

--update

Using datejs, just write something like:

```
(new Date).clearTime()
          .addSeconds(15457)
          .toString('H:mm:ss');
```

--update

Nowadays date.js is outdated and not maintained, so use "Moment.js",

Comment: It doesn't return days? when using your first function

Comment: Ahhh, Just check my DDHHMMSS function

Comment: Is their no way I can display this in a user friendly format?

Comment: What is your definition for user friendly format ?...  return [d, pad(h), pad(m),pad(s)].join(':') modify this, Like adding dats, hours and all

Comment: Check the update: you will get  2days : Xhours :  Xminutes : X seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use a third-party plugin, try: [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

For more info on how to use this for future dates, see the question:

[Like timeago, but in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929428/like-timeago-but-in-the-future)